# How to create kibana visualization with field alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, analytics, data-visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

I need to create Kibana visualization by aggregating user_id field but instead of displaying row user_id, I want to display user_name field to make it really worthy. Any suggestion how to do that?

Example: I have a type user_actions which have following fields:

- id
- user_name
- user_id
- action_name
- created
- ...

Now I want to visualize this data by counting user_id field over time, but instead of displaying user_id I want to display username.

Example:

- John  1000
- Jane  500
- Doe   350

We normally do this easily in SQL group by statement. Hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Could you make the question a bit more specific by showing what kind of data you have and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @FabianFagerholm added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is being discussed for almost two years in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1896).

> It would be handy to have somewhere to put some JSON to display
>   shorter/prettier field name aliases throughout Kibana.
>   <...>
>   So instead of seeing
>   "store.address.state" in a dropdown box or in a visualization you
>   would see "State".

Right now (since [Kibana 4.5](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-5-0-released)) you're able to change only **Metric Aggregations** names.